# is there any way to use RAM and VRAM at the same time on Pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

When I use Keras , It loads the input dataset on RAM a

and loads networks on VRAM, so that I could train vary large network.

However I cannot find the way to do so with pytorch

and this makes me using so small memory I guess.

Is there any way to use both RAM on pytorch ?

Comment: What makes you think that PyTorch is not already doing it?

Comment: @hkchengrex I am a very newbie on pytorch so please tell me how to

Comment: Once you define an instance of a Module invoking the `.cuda()` class method of your module transfers all the model parameters and buffers to GPU memory.

Comment: @jodag Is it OK to transfer model to GPU only and keep the loaded data on RAM ?

Comment: The data returned from your dataset needs to be transfered to the same GPU as the model before passing it into the model. This is usually done immediately before invoking the model. For example inside the `for x, y in dataloader:` loop you would have something like `x, y = x.cuda(), y.cuda()` to move the minibatch to the same device as the model, followed by `output = model(x)` to invoke your model's forward pass and `loss = criterion(output, y)` to compute the loss function.